# Cant get Express to redirect to main page after user login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest

I'm trying to setup a user login section. The user_router is sending a JSON response just fine however I can't get Express to send a new html page back to the client. The first page that is offered is login.html which has the submission form for the login verification. The goal is to send back a 200 status message along with the actual app.html page upon login verification. The status message is working however the Express sendFile is not redirecting the browser to the app.html page. What am I doing wrong here?

**The app.js file is loaded first. It has the following config:**

```
const user_router = require( './router/user_router' );
const path = require( 'path' );
const public_directory = path.join( __dirname, '../public' );
const express = require( 'express' );
const app = express();
app.use(express.static( public_directory , {index: 'login.html'}));
app.use( user_router );
app.use( express.json() );
```

**The user_router.js file where the validation and redirect should happen.**

```
const auth = require( '../middlewear/auth' );
const express = require( 'express' );
const User = require( '../model/user_model' );
const router = new express.Router();
router.use( express.json() );

router.post( '/users/login' , async ( req , res ) => {
        
    try {       
        const user = await User.find_by_credentials( req.body.email , req.body.password );      
        const token = await user.create_token();
        const path = require( 'path' );     
        const app = path.join( __dirname, '../../public/app.html' );        
        res.sendFile( app );
        res.send( { user , token } );
    }
    catch( err ){
        res.status( 400 ).send();
    }
});
```

Comment: The `res.send` overrides the `res.sendFile`. What purpose shall the `res.send` serve?

Comment: res.send is sending the user profile (from mongodb) along with the authentication token. I have tried sendFile after send but then I get an error saying something about "you can't change the headers after they are already set"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to issue a redirect response the you need to use the [`redirect` method](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect).

The `sendFile` method sends a file … for the URL the client asked for. It very much does not redirect them.

The `send` method also sends a response that isn't a redirect.

---

What's more, a request can only have one response to it (well, unless you make use of [the new features in HTTP/2](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/guide-http2-server-push/))

`redirect`, `sendFile`, or `send`: Pick **one** (which should be  `redirect` if you want to redirect!)

Comment: Hmm interesting. So I should use redirect to send the new html page to the client and res.send to send back the http status ?

Comment: No. You use `redirect` to redirect (which is what you explicitly asked for), `sendFile` to send a file (although the static middleware is usually a better choice) and `status` (not `send`) to set the status *before* you send anything.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. I see where redirect allows you to also pass a status along with it. However I also need to return the user profile and token. If I can only use one of the response methods how can you also send the client a profile and token?

Comment: Traditionally you would put those in a cookie.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing me in the right direction.